# Using Wget to download single images from a website using the the img src URL where img class="decoded"

Tags: images, php, download, cygwin, wget

I want to get single images off a website.  The website has photos.  Clicking on the photos leads to another page.  I want to get the photos from the img src tag in the html.  I already have unix code to extract the img src lines I want.

Example:
img src="http://website.com/photo.php?user_id=231&photo_id=23&thumbnail=1&SID=kdede19f8z1t38be1"

When I use wget to download this URL, I get a null file.

When I manually enter this URL into my browser, the image loads in the middle of the screen.  When I click on the properties, it is a JPEG file.  When I look at the html source for the page, it gives the following:

```
<html><head> … </head><body><img class="decoded" src="http://website.com/photo.php?user_id=231&photo_id=23&thumbnail=1&SID=kdede19f8z1t38be1" alt="http://website.com/photo.php?user_id=231&photo_id=23&thumbnail=1&SID=kdede19f8z1t38be1"></img></body></html>
```

The only thing I can figure is that it has to do with the tag:

```
<img class="decoded"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I figured it out.  Because the site is php, I needed to add --trust-server-names as an argument to the wget command.  Once I did that, I was able to download the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Because the site is php, I needed to add --trust-server-names as an argument to the wget.  Once I did that, I could download the image without a problem.